# Promise resolves before the function finishes

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following code,  `attenCalendar.refresh();` method calls a sequence of requests/responses and executes asynchronously. It needs to be finished in order to `attenCalendar.getItem`  be successful. I used promises to solve it, but apparently promise resolves before the refresh completes and causes to `attenCalendar.getItem` returns null.
How can I block the sequence till `refresh()` finishes?

```
yield promise_attendee1_assert();

function attendeeRefresh(){
  let deferred = Promise.defer();
  attenCalendar.refresh();
  deferred.resolve("refreshed");
  return deferred.promise;
}

function promise_attendee1_assert(){
  let deferred = Promise.defer();
  let promise = attendeeRefresh();

  promise.then(function onRefreshed(refreshNote) {
    dump("refreshedattendee"+refreshNote);
    attenCalendar.getItem(attendItem.id, {
         onGetResult: function onGetResult(cal, stat, type, detail, count, items) {
             retrievedItem = items[0];
//prints null
             dump("\nattendeeitem:"+retrievedItem.title);
         },
         onOperationComplete: function() {
          deferred.resolve();
         }
       });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: As you are working with promises, it would make sense to have `attenCalendar.refresh()` return a promise.

Comment: Show us the code for `refresh`

Comment: I checked, it doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @Marlio if `.refresh` does not provide a way for you to hook on its completion (by accepting a callback or returning a promise) then you can't hook on its completion - simple as that. Promise deferreds don't know by themselves when an async calculation is done.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that was a huge piece of code in mozilla, I think somewhere there can be a observer returned. http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/providers/caldav/calDavCalendar.js#1437
I also wanted to make sure that if there is anyway to ensure a method completion if it does not return a promise or a callback.

Comment: @Marlio method completion? Sure, when it returns it is completed. However, methods typically set async handlers and unless _those_ provide a way to hook on you simply _can't_. You can always degrade to polling every few milliseconds for a side effect - but the real solution is to figure out how to hook on completion - which we can only help you with if you show us the source.

Comment: If you read the source you'll see you can call `replayChangesOn` with a listener that has a `onResult` method that gets called on changes.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I just found it. Took me a while to digest the code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sure, please post an answer when you're done with the solution :)